# How to create realistic blinking eyes effect using Velocity JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, velocity.js

I'm trying to learn using Velocity JS for some SVG effects, right now I'm trying to do a simple blinking effect but I'm not actually sure how to make it look realistic. At the moment I'm using the `r` property and with easing looks silly. Can anyone provide me with some advice on creating a more realistic effect? Like how do I blink from the center of the eyes, flicker a couple of times, delay then repeat?

**Link:** http://codepen.io/styler/pen/XJYWgr?editors=101

**JS**

```
Velocity(eyes,
{
  r: 2
},{
  loop: true,
  delay: 300,
  duration: 1
}
);
```